# Display opening hours from google map without showing map

Tags: google-maps

I need to display opening hours for a store. Opening hours information for this store is regularly updated on google's database. Now I need to show it in one of our website but without showing the google map. Can we do that? Every example I found to show is with the map object but we don't need that at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues) not coding.

Comment: Hi,Can you help t to understand how it is off topic or legal issue. I just need to know if this is possible/permissible.

Comment: Permissible is a legal issue, has nothing to do with coding and is off topic for StackOverflow.  It is certainly possible to do.

Comment: If this is a code question, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi, I am able to see opening hours for "Hershey's Chocolate World" in google but when I try to see opening hours for the same store in API, I don't. What could be the reason. I used https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder  to find the place Id for this place and API used is https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid<place_id> & key=<api key>. Coul d you please help